# Is there a function like prototype.toArray in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, class, object

I want to change the value, that is returned form a JavaScript object with the following code:

```
F.prototype.valueOf = function(){return "foo";}
F.prototype.toString = Id.valueOf();
```

"F" being the JavaScript class and "foo" the string i am returning.
This works fine when calling an alert like so:

```
alert(F());    //alerts foo
```

But is there any way, that the value of an object can be an array? Maybe something like

```
F.prototype.valueOf = function(){return ["foo", "bar"];}
F.prototype.toArray = Id.valueOf();
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`valueOf` can only convert to and return primitive values, so you can't force it into returning an `Array`. You could try to use `JSON.Stringify` to return a JSON string, which could be parsed later on <sup>**1**</sup>. See also [this article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript.html), or the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

You could of course also write a custom 'getter' function to retrieve your custom valueOf, something like:

```
F.prototype.getValue = function() {return ['foo', 'bar']};
```

<sup>**1**</sup> e.g.

```
var someobj = {
               bar: 1, some: [1,2,3], 
               x: 'string', foo:[{a:1,b:2},2,3], 
               valueOf: function(){return JSON.stringify(this);}
              };
someobj.valueOf(); 
//=> "{"bar":1,"some":[1,2,3],"x":"string","foo":[{"a":1,"b":2},2,3]}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Too bad though, the array I want to return contains mixed data types, not only strings. So I can't use JSON I guess...

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't overwrite `valueOf` in this case.

Comment: @Ood: see the example, mixed values shouldn't be a problem. @Tibos: yep, if one needs a special value from `valueOf`, one could also write some `get`-method for it.

Comment: Thanks, this will probably work for what I'm trying to accomplish!